# Sort array of objects in Processing Javascript mode

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, processing

I'm building a little game in Processing's Javascript mode and have my enemies as objects in an array. I'd like to sort them by their Y coordinate to draw them in vertical order (and not overlap and look weird). Since they are generated and respawned over the course of the game, I need to sort this array repeatedly.

I've done this before in the regular Java mode using `Arrays.sort()` and `Comparable`, but that doesn't work in JS mode.

Any ideas? I found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects/979289#979289) but can't figure out how to implement it:

`enemies.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.yPos) - parseFloat(b.yPos) } );`

**EDIT**
As requested, here's a bit more context:

```
Enemy[] enemies = new Enemy[10];

void setup() {
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    enemies[i] = new Enemy();
  }
  enemies.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.yPos) - parseFloat(b.yPos) } );
}

class Enemy {
  float xPos, yPos;

  Enemy() {
    xPos = random(0,width);
    yPos = random(0,height);
  }
}
```

This throws an error on the `sort` line: `unexpected token: {`.

I know one can mix pure JS within Processing JS, but in this case it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: What is wrong with that solution?

Comment: Assuming `enemies` refers to an array of objects that each have a `yPos` property that should work. (Although you don't need the `parseFloat()`, you can use `return a.yPos - b.yPos;`.)

Comment: To clarify - that code above might well work, I just don't know how to use it within the Processing JS framework.

Comment: What do you mean by Processing JS framework? Please show us a piece of code where this code doesn't produce expected result.

Comment: @JeffThompson "To clarify - that code above might well work, I just don't know how to use it within the Processing JS framework." Copy, paste.